# Java driver: how to get the objectId of an updated object with Mongodb's updateFirst method

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm trying to get the objectId of an object that I have updated - this is my java code using the java driver:

```
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("color").is("pink"));
    Update update = new Update();
    update.set("name", name);
    WriteResult writeResult = mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, Colors.class);

    Log.e("object id", writeResult.getUpsertedId().toString());
```

The log message returns null. I'm using a mongo server 3.0 on mongolab as I'm on the free tier so it shouldn't return null. My mongo shell is also:

> MongoDB shell version: 3.0.7

Is there an easy way to return the  object ID for the doc that I have just updated? What is the point of the method getUpsertedId() if I cannot return the upsertedId?

To do what I want, I currently have to issue two queries which is highly cumbersome:

```
    //1st query - updating the object first
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("color").is("pink"));
    Update update = new Update();
    update.set("name", name);
    WriteResult writeResult = mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, Colors.class);
    //2nd query - find the object so that I can get its objectid
    Query queryColor = new Query();
    queryColor.addCriteria(Criteria.where("color").is("pink"));
    queryColor.addCriteria(Criteria.where("name").is(name));
    Color color = mongoTemplate.findOne(queryColor, Color.class);
    Log.e("ColorId", color.getId());
```

As per David's answer, I even tried his suggestion to rather use upsert on the template, so I changed the code to the below and it still does not work:

```
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("color").is("pink"));
    Update update = new Update();
    update.set("name", name);
    WriteResult writeResult = mongoTemplate.upsert(query, update, Colors.class);

    Log.e("object id", writeResult.getUpsertedId().toString());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simon, I think its possible to achieve in one query. What you need is a different method called [**findAndModify()**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#db-collection-findandmodify).

In java driver for mongoDB, it has a method called **[findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, options)](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#findOneAndUpdate-org.bson.conversions.Bson-org.bson.conversions.Bson-)**.

This method returns the document that was updated. Depending on the options you specified for the method, this will either be the document as it was before the update or as it is after the update. If no documents matched the query filter, then null will be returned. Its not required to pass options, in that case it will return the document that was updated before update operation was applied.

A quick look at the mongoTemplate java driver docs here:  http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/FindAndModifyOptions.html tells me that you can use the method call:

```
public <T> T findAndModify(Query query,
                           Update update,
                           FindAndModifyOptions options,
                           Class<T> entityClass)
```

You can also change the FindAndModifyOptions class to take on an 'upsert' if the item was not found in the query.If it is found, the object will just be modified.

Comment: This would be a great answer if it had an example ;)

Comment: @Markus Thank you, I am not much of a java guy myself. Can you edit the answer if you know the code?

Comment: I think in theory this would work but I'm not 100% sure yet as I have no time to test it lately. I think the method call in java would be findAndModify : http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html#findAndModify-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.FindAndModifyOptions-java.lang.Class-

Answer (score 1):

Upsert only applies if both

1. The update options had upsert on
2. A new document was actually created.

Your query neither has upsert enabled, nor creates a new document. Therefore it makes perfect sense that the `getUpsertedId()` returns null here.

Unfortunately it is not possible to get what you want in a single call with the current API; you need to split it into two calls. This is further indicated by the Mongo shell API for [WriteResults](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/WriteResult/#WriteResult._id):

> The _id of the document inserted by an upsert. **Returned only if an
>   upsert results in an insert.**

Comment: Hi David, even if I used the method: WriteResult writeResult = mongoTemplate.upsert(query, update, Colors.class); and try to obtain the id with getUpsertedId() on it, it still does not return the id.

Comment: @Simon It sounds like you are running upsert on an already existing document though, so that makes sense. See point #2. Try making the query `query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("color").is("adasdasdsadsa"));`

Comment: But in point 1, you said that the update options has upsert on. In my case, the mongoTemplate has upsert on so it should work...Also the code you suggested above would not make sense as then I would have to create a new document. I'm not creating a new document but just amending my existing doc through an upsert otherwise, I could easily do a save and get the id through the mongoTemplate.save method.

Comment: @Simon I think you misunderstood, both conditions 1 and 2 have to be true. I'll update to clarify Also, the point of upsert is that it only happens if the document you are searching for doesn't exist then you are creating a new document. Otherwise its just a regular update. So as you said, you are just amending an existing doc, therefore no upsert is done and no upsertId will be returned.

Comment: OK - understood but still need to think about it a little. In my case, I cannot use the save method as that could result in duplicated docs, I think the two method calls is the way to go unless I receive any other answers to this question.

Comment: @Simon Yes, you are correct, two method calls is the only way to get the `_id` back. The other question is, why do you want to get the `_id` back? Why do you care?

Comment: Well the id is useful to get back because I want to associate the color to different mongodb objects. Let say I have a collection of clothes. I want to go dress and hats has a color of pink. If I can get back the color id from the color collection, I can associate it to the objects in the clothes collection.

Comment: @Simon Yeah, you'll need 2 queries for that

Answer (score 0):

This is an example to do this with findOneAndUpdate(filter,update,options) in Scala:

```
val findOneAndUpdateOptions = new FindOneAndUpdateOptions
findOneAndUpdateOptions.returnDocument(ReturnDocument.AFTER)
val filter = Document.parse("{\"idContrato\":\"12345\"}")
val update = Document.parse("{ $set: {\"descripcion\": \"New Description\" } }")
val response = collection.findOneAndUpdate(filter,update,findOneAndUpdateOptions)
println(response)
```